# switch codes of countdown timer from javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to switch this codes for countdown timer from javascript to jquery so i can include more than 1 countdown timer in the same page with different div ids..

I'm not good with javascript or jquery, i swear i have wasted more than 15 hours for that !!

Here is the main page code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "06/25/2013 5:00 AM";
CurrentDate = "<?= strftime('%c') ?>";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
<script src="js/countdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

countdown.js file

```
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
  if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
    s = "0" + s;
  return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
}

function CountBack(secs) {
  if (secs < 0) {
    document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
    return;
  }
  DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

  document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
  if (CountActive)
    setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}

function putspan() {
 document.write("<span id='cntdwn'></span>");
}


if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
  CountActive = true;
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
  FinishMessage = "";
if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
  CountStepper = -1;
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
  LeadingZero = true;


CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0)
  CountActive = false;
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
putspan();
var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
var dnow = new Date(CurrentDate);
if(CountStepper>0)
  ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
else
  ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
CountBack(gsecs);
```

Any help please??

Comment: Why do you think you would need jQuery for that? It will only make it slower. Just wrap the whole thing in a function and make the hardwired id a parameter. Oh, and fix the `setTimeout`.

Comment: Any example please ? i really will appreciate that..also what do you think about "setTimeout" i think it work fine ??

Comment: @user2203703 did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

> so i can include more than 1 countdown timer in the same page with different div ids..

Therefore you have to make all those global config variables parameters of a function. And add an parameter for the id.

So wrap your whole script in

```
function makeCounter(DisplayId, TargetDate, CurrentDate, CountActive, CountStepper, LeadingZero, DisplayFormat, FinishMessage) {
    …
}
```

which then will be invoked (after the script is loaded, so have to change their order) with

```
makeCounter("cntdwn",
            "06/25/2013 5:00 AM",
            "<?= strftime('%c') ?>",
            true, -1, true,
            "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.",
            "It is finally here!");
```

Then replace each occurrence of the string `cntdwn` with the `DisplayId` variable.

That was the basics and your script ought to work, but it needs two other bugfixes:

- Make reasonable use of local variables, declare them with the [`var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). I found `s`, `DisplayStr`, `ddiff` and `gsecs` undeclared, but I may have missed other ones.
- Calling [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) with a to-be-`eval`ed-string is not recommended and did only work when `CountBack` was in the global scope, which it is not any more. Instead, pass a function:

  ```
  setTimeout(function() {
      CountBack(secs+CountStepper);
  }, SetTimeOutPeriod);
  ```

Now it will work. For convenience, you also might lowercase variable and function names since they are no constructors, but there's no necessity.